# Angular 7 not sending post data to api

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have an `asp.net` backend service. The backend api is working fine from `postman`

[image]

but doing same thing from angular doesn't work. The body doesn't send to server. I am using angular 7.

This is my code.

**dairy service**

```
public addNewDairy(value) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + "dairy", value)
      .pipe(
        map(success => success),
        catchError(this.hes.handleError) // then handle the error
      );
  }
```

and the component

```
requestForRegistration(value) {
    this.jqxLoader.open();
    this.ds.addNewDairy(value).subscribe(res => {
      this.jqxLoader.close();
      this.message = "Requested for activation.";
      this.notification.open();
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.jqxLoader.close();
      this.message = "Something went wrong please try again!";
      this.notification.open();
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you debugged it and confirmed that your value was not undefined ?

Comment: Yes sir. There value presented. It is being printed inside `addNewDairy` method

Comment: "Http" is deprecated. Could you please try using HttpClient instead?

Comment: has used the same `HttpClient` and imported from `@angular/common/http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 204 is coming from the OPTIONS request that the browser sends as part of it being a cross-domain request. Once the OPTIONS request comes back successfully with a 200, your real request would go up. Postman would not be sending the OPTIONS request, since you are going directly to the API in that instance. Your Angular looks fine - I would verify in your asp.net backend has CORS enabled - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors.

Comment: I already enabled CORS at `startup.cs` using 

     ` app.UseCors(builder =>
         builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));`